# How to create a many to many relationship in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Let me be more specific in my question.

I have a many to many relationship. I have an Opportunity and I have items.

In my Opportunity/Create view I want to be able to "add" as many items from the items list as I want. So when I click the save button on the create form, I would be potentially saving many items that would be associated with this record.

So the only way to do this is to include a click box for every item in my items table? How would I do something like Click this button to insert a new item from a drop down list?

Models:

```
public class Opportunity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyOpportunity { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

}

public class ItemsToOpportunity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OpportunityId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: When you ask 'how would I do this', what are you looking for help with? The code structure? The UI?

Comment: I think I have the 3 models correct..I'm just not sure how to implement it in the controller and view so that when I create  new opportunity I can add as many items as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comment, it sounds like you just need to provide a form with multiple checkboxes or so.

Then, when you post to the server, the shared name of the checkboxes becomes a comma delimited set of Ids to use.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="myNewOpportunityItems" value="1"><span>Item 1</span>
 <input type="checkbox" name="myNewOpportunityItems" value="2"><span>Item 1</span>
 <input type="checkbox" name="myNewOpportunityItems" value="3"><span>Item 1</span>
 <input type="checkbox" name="myNewOpportunityItems" value="4"><span>Item 1</span>
```

Then, when the user selects the checkboxes of the items they want to associate, that gets posted as a comma delimited string:

```
 public ActionResult MyPostActionResult(string myNewOpportunityItems)
 {
       // myNewOpportunityItems == "1,3,4";
 }
```